# Identify Relationship between two columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns in a dataframe as follows, namely Letter and Number

[image: Dataframe]

I want to do following

1. In the above table letter A is repeated two times in column "Letter" which I want to classify as "One to Many" in a new column.
2. 15 is repeated two times in number column which i want to classify as "many to one".
3. Letter B, C and Number 5, 6 occurred only one time in each column therefore should be classified as one to one.
4. For other should be classified as many to many.

Expected output is shown below.
[image: Output]

5. I tried using `groupby` function by shifting the column name, it helped to identify item 1 and item 2 separately.

I want to do it in single function, Please help.....

Comment: If you can already identify the two halves of the one/many relationship, just write a function that takes those two parts and puts them together.

Comment: Elaborating on @BrenBarn's comment: You can do the logic for the two columns independently because your string is just a composition of the outcomes for the two columns.

Comment: But  `(F,20), (G,20)` , rows 6,7, shouldn´t be `Many to One`, like `(D,15), (E,15)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function like this:

```
import pandas as pd

letter = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'F', 'G']
number = [10,11,5,6,15,15,20,20,25,28]
data = {'letter': letter, 'number': number}    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def relationship(letter, number):
    number_of_letters = {}
    number_of_numbers = {}
    relationship = [] 

    for i in letter:
        if i in number_of_letters:
            number_of_letters[i] += 1
        else:
            number_of_letters[i] = 1    
    for i in number:
        if i in number_of_numbers:
            number_of_numbers[i] += 1
        else:
            number_of_numbers[i] = 1    
    for i in range(len(letter)):
        if number_of_letters[letter[i]] == 1 and number_of_numbers[number[i]] == 1:
            relationship.append('One to One')
        elif number_of_letters[letter[i]] > 1 and number_of_numbers[number[i]] == 1:
            relationship.append('One to Many')
        elif number_of_letters[letter[i]] == 1 and number_of_numbers[number[i]] > 1:
            relationship.append('Many to One') 
        elif number_of_letters[letter[i]] > 1 and number_of_numbers[number[i]] > 1:
            relationship.append('Many to Many') 

    return relationship 

df['relationship'] = relationship(letter, number)
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be your solution

```py
import pandas as pd

d1 = ['A','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','F','G']
d2 = [10,11,5,6,15,15,20,20,25,28]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(d1,d2)), columns = ['col1', 'col2'])


df['one to one'] = (df.groupby('col2')['col1'].transform(lambda x:x.nunique()==1) & df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x:x.nunique()==1))


df['many to one'] = (df.groupby('col2')['col1'].transform(lambda x:x.nunique()>1) & df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x:x.nunique()==1))


df['one to many'] = (df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x:x.nunique()>1) & df.groupby('col2')['col1'].transform(lambda x:x.nunique()==1))



df['many to many'] = (df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(lambda x:x.nunique()>1) & df.groupby('col2')['col1'].transform(lambda x:x.nunique()>1))


import numpy as np

conditions = [
    (df['one to one'] == True), (df['one to many'] == True),(df['many to one'] == True),(df['many to many'] == True)]
choices = ['one to one', 'one to many', 'many to one','many to many']
df['relation'] = np.select(conditions, choices)


df.drop(['one to one', 'one to many', 'many to one','many to many'], axis = 1)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I want the item 8 and 9 also to be classified as many to many relationship, since the letter is repeated to numbers such 20 and 25.

Comment: but actually F -> 20,25 (one to many) and G -> 20,28 (one to many)